# Android Studio/Gradle build can't find custom Application class

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm using the new Android Studio and Gradle to build a test project.  I set it up in the default way (new project wizard).  Everything seems to work OK, except that I specify a custom  Application instance in the manifest file.  The app builds OK, but then crashes when run on the device with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "co.touchlab.android.testapp.MyApplication" on path: /data/app/co.touchlab.android.testapp-1.apk
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
```

Intellij seems to think everything is OK, and if I take out the custom app it works (until I hit a screen that tries to use it, of course).

I'm probably going to copy this over into my normal build dir and give it a whirl on idea 12 till this is sorted, but its obviously something to figure out.  Will try a totally stock app with a custom Application class and see if that has trouble as well.

Comment: Moved and import into Idea 12.  Zero problems (besides normal bugs).

Comment: Let me clarify for whoever voted this down without an explanation, I moved into intellij to continue working on the project, but I'd like to figure out how to fix this to use the android studio.

Comment: How did you set up the dependencies? You need to make sure build.gradle is properly setup. Don't use the UI in Studio to set the dependency.

Comment: Yeah, thats kind of the question.  How do I tell it to include that class?  Its in my src dir.  the app works otherwise if I take out the custom app declaration (till I hit an activity that tries to cast it).  It would seem like gradle selectively doesn't include it.  I have put other local jars into the gradle build file, and they seem to load fine.  Do I need to explicitly say "this is my custom application class"?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your build folder manually?  Android Studio doesn't seem to do a proper clean.

Comment: any updates/solutions?

Comment: We've been using intellij for a while, so haven't had much reason to try Studio again.  I would assume by now its far more stable and this works OK. Would need to try it, though. This problem appeared right after Google I/O. Very, very early build.

Comment: This question is EXTREMELY out of date.  No longer applies.  Not sure I can remove, though.

Answer (score -1):

Open your build.gradle file for your app and add this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'PATH_OF_MISSING_CLASS_HERE'
}
```